# Generate xml from html form and parse to url using javascript or php

Tags: javascript, php, html, xml

Want to generate xml from html form as shown below in to an xml and the xml shoul parse to a url. can u suggest..

```
      <div id="line5" class="clear">
        <div class="fieldType">
            <h4>Partner provided unique ID</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="fieldValue">
            <input type="text" name="Param2" maxlength="24">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="line6" class="clear">
        <div class="fieldType">
            <h4>LoanAmount :</h4>
            </div>
        <div class="fieldValue">
            <input type="text" name="LoanAmount" maxlength="60">
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: could you tell what you have tried till now

Comment: i have created an xml template and stored it as a string now i need to parse the string to an url